# Everytime same video gets uploaded + Assets Library

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, assetslibrary, avurlasset

```
    ImgVidData =[[NSData alloc]init];

    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = alAsset.defaultRepresentation;
    NSURL *movieURL = representation.url;
    NSURL *uploadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"] stringByAppendingString:@".mov"]];

  //  ImgVidData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"] stringByAppendingString:@".mp4"]];

    AVAsset *asset      = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:movieURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *session =
    [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];

    session.outputFileType  = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    session.outputURL       = uploadURL;
    videoURL=uploadURL;
          [session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        if (session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
        {
            NSLog(@"output Video URL %@",uploadURL);

        }



    }];
    ImgVidData    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:session.outputURL];
```

Above is the code , i have implemented inside didFinishPickingAssets:(NSArray *)assets

I'm picking up the video and uploading the video to server. I'm fetching uploaded video URL and converting it into NSdata and uploading it to server.

STRANGE : everytime I'm getting same video uploaded to server which i choose first time. i choose different video everytime but same videos get uplaoded. 
Any help !!

Comment: Why `ImgVidData =[[NSData alloc]init];` and `ImgVidData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:session.outputURL];`? The first one shouldn't be useful. When is called the second one? Note that your export is asynchronous.  When you write, do you overwrite? For example, if a file exist already (test.mov), what happens?

Comment: I have just added that line to check ImgVidData =[[NSData alloc]init]; but nothing happens , i have tried . can you tell me exactly what should i do as a change so i will get unique video everytime

Comment: then put this code  `ImgVidData    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:session.outputURL];` inside the block and try whether its working or not

Comment: i did that already 
 [session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        if (session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
        {
}
this block doesn't get called

Comment: instead of putting break point just put any `logs`, and can you explain me about what is `uploadURL`

Comment: video URL : file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FC30EEDF-8845-457C-B987-67A12277F30B/tmp/test.mov

Comment: seems like there is problem in session : AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed
i think its getting failed